# Cordova open link to app in new app window android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I'm facing a problem in Cordova where i want to link to another app thats installed on the phone but the app opens inside my cordova app and does not open the app in a new app window.

[See here there are 2 instances of the Yammer app, one is inside my Cordova app (Alkmaar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwwwz.jpg)

i'm using window.open(url, '_system'); and the plugin inAppBrowser is installed.
Code snippet:

```
$("body").on("click","a.tile", function(e){

           var url = $(this).data("url");
           var playstore = $(this).attr("data-playstore");
           var appstore = $(this).attr("data-appstore");
           var deeplink = $(this).attr("data-deeplink");

           if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 960 ) {
             window.open(deeplink, '_system');
```

The problem here is that if i login in Yammer the app crashes since its probably having 2 login sessions.

Is there any way i can make sure it opens the installed app in a new window??

PS: this problem does not occur on iOs, only on Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use this java code:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("appPackage");
this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Or you can use below plugin for launching apps

https://github.com/dmedvinsky/cordova-startapp